# Test: is caller from Internet Explorer ended?

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, com

(sorry for my bad english)

In a my.vbs I start the IE with:

```
Set oIE_ = WScript.CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_" )
```

and make some settings in the IE with:

```
oIE_.navigate my.html
```

Then I have this Sub:

```
Sub IE_onQuit
   msgbox "IE closed !"
End Sub
```

With this callback-Sub the my.vbs can ‎recognize, if the IE was closed. This works very good.

But now I want also ‎recognize in my.html (with Javascript), if the caller my.vbs was finished/closed. If I close my.vbs, then the IE ‎keep going. I found no way, to start the IE as a child-process, ‎in order to if the vbs was closed then the IE ‎also closed ‎automatically.

I'm searching now for 3 days with no luck. I want tell more, but my english is not enough. 
Can anyone help me please?